# Anyone knows of a question answer script based on codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Anyone knows of a question answer script based on codeigniter ?
Commercial or open-source ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find such scripts using Codeigniter, but you might want to take a look at this one, which uses Django framework.

http://code.google.com/p/soclone/

or you might want to browse around other scripts:

http://www.enfew.com/9-free-stackoverflow-clones-and-qa-scripts/